# Retrieving name of all files in a folder with csv format

Tags: ssis

I would like to show name of CSV-files, which are in folder via message box.

for this job, I have a for each loop and a script task I have also defined a sting variable `Filename`

I have set Enumarato for foreachloop to `Foreach-File-Enumarator` and set the Variable to my variable

[image]

and in the expression did so:
[image]

Now I would like to see the name of ech file with this code:

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            string value = (string) Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value;
            MessageBox.Show(value);
        }
```

but it doesnt work for me. Message box is pop up only for the first file and not for the others
Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your control flow?

Comment: I'm confused by the Expressions - you are changing the name of a task based on the current file name? Isn't that going to break the name for SSIS as it doesn't allow periods?